# SQLite rollback robustness

Tags: sqlite

Oracle, SQL Server, DB2 and all major commercial databases work fine with multiple levels of redo by many different users.

Is SQLite robust enough to do this also or are there limitations on the transaction handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite database is in a file on disc. if you want to do you have to do multiple database writes, put them inside a transaction. Since every write will lock the file(db). SQLite behaves well with large transactions though. I have no solid data compare this with other databases you mentioned but large transactions are handled well in SQLite.

Comment: Thanks that's great. It's am amazing piece of code. What about multiple users or rather multiple separate transactions from a single application?